# Completely Maximize C# winform and hiding open window icons at bottom

Tags: c#, maximize-window

I already set `this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;` and everything looks ok but the Windows open-window icons (such as my browser at the bottom of the page) is still visible.

How to make it invisible?

Comment: I think the word you are looking for is "full screen" (like when you press F11 in a browser).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just figured out the answer
`TopMost` must be set to `true` together with `FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None` and  `Bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds`.